# JWT filter and spring security control flow in a Spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am very new to spring security. I am trying to implement `JWT` filters in my web application to make it stateless. I have piece of code, when users hits the `/login` path, the control goes to the  method,

```
public LoginResponse login( 
AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, Device device )
        throws WebappException
{
    // Perform the security
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()));

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
/** some more logic**/
```

Here I am not understanding the purpose of 

`final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()));`

Please guide me!
`AuthenticationRequest` has two fields `userName` and `password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authenticationManager.authenticate()` method passes the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to the `AuthenticationProvider` and tries to authenticate to user with provided username and password.

- It returns an `Authentication` object with granted authorities if successful,
- It throws an exception if authentication fails.

You can then call `authentication.isAuthenticated()` to know if the token has been authenticated.

If you want to access a database to check authentication, you should use the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` implementation (or `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`).
It retrieves user details from the interface `UserDetailsService`. So you need to create a class `MyUserDetailsService` which implements `UserDetailsService` overriding the `loadUserByUsername(String username)` method and returning `UserDetails`.
`UserDetails` contains username, password, authorities. Create your own `MyUserdetails` class wich implements `UserDetails` interface.
Then, configure Spring to reference your cutom class:

```
DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
authProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
```

More details on http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Or you can also use the JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer to directly specify you datasource and SQL queries:

```
@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
         .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, enabled from users where username=?")
         .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}
```

Regarding JWT, I think your login method checks at first the authentication of a user and then should build a JWT with the user details and return it to the browser.
Then the client can resend this token to the server and this JWT will be decrypted and validated by another method.
More information on https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java

Comment: How `final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()));` performs checking of username and password? I am simply passing what user has submitted in the request. How it will be validated against the data in the database?